# Spark: StringIndexer on sentences

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to do something StringIndexer on a column of sentences, i.e. transforming list of words to list of integers.

For example:

**input dataset**:

```
  (1, ["I", "like", "Spark"])
  (2, ["I", "hate", "Spark"])
```

I expected the output after **StringIndexer** to be like:

```
  (1, [0, 2, 1])
  (2, [0, 3, 1])
```

Ideally, I would like to make such transformation as part of Pipeline, so that I can chain couple transformer together and serialize for online serving.

Is this something Spark support natively?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard `Transformers` used for converting text to features are [`CountVectorizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer)

> CountVectorizer and CountVectorizerModel aim to help convert a collection of text documents to vectors of token counts.

or [`HashingTF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF):

> Maps a sequence of terms to their term frequencies using the hashing trick. Currently we use Austin Appleby's MurmurHash 3 algorithm (MurmurHash3_x86_32) to calculate the hash code value for the term object. Since a simple modulo is used to transform the hash function to a column index, it is advisable to use a power of two as the numFeatures parameter; otherwise the features will not be mapped evenly to the columns.

Both have `binary` option which can used to switch from count to binary vector.

There is no builtin `Transfomer` that can give exact result you want (it wouldn't be useful for ML algorithms) buy you can `explode` apply `StringIndexer`,  and `collect_list` / `collect_set`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline


val df = Seq(
  (1, Array("I", "like", "Spark")), (2, Array("I", "hate", "Spark"))
).toDF("id", "words")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new SQLTransformer()
    .setStatement("SELECT id, explode(words) as word FROM __THIS__"),
  new StringIndexer().setInputCol("word").setOutputCol("index"),
  new SQLTransformer()
    .setStatement("""SELECT id, COLLECT_SET(index) AS values 
                     FROM __THIS__ GROUP BY id""")
))

pipeline.fit(df).transform(df).show

// +---+---------------+                      
// | id|         values|
// +---+---------------+
// |  1|[0.0, 1.0, 3.0]|
// |  2|[2.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
// +---+---------------+
```

With `CountVectorizer` and `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._


spark.udf.register("indices", (v: Vector) => v.toSparse.indices)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("vector"),
  new SQLTransformer()
    .setStatement("SELECT *, indices(vector) FROM __THIS__")
))

pipeline.fit(df).transform(df).show

// +---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
// | id|           words|              vector|UDF:indices(vector)|
// +---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
// |  1|[I, like, Spark]|(4,[0,1,3],[1.0,1...|          [0, 1, 3]|
// |  2|[I, hate, Spark]|(4,[0,1,2],[1.0,1...|          [0, 1, 2]|
// +---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Curious, why you say this not useful for ML. The reason I tried to do this, is I am transforming the data in spark and then feed transformed data into Tensorflow framework to train. TF model want to consume the "sentences" for NLP processing.

Comment: Normally ML tools expect a fixed size vector representation of the data and you cannot just pass list of indices.

Comment: Ah, maybe I did not phrase my question probably. When I say list of indices, I meant array of indices. The problem I tried to solve is, I need transform raw sentences into fixed size vector of numbers. if the sentences have longer length than the size, I will cut it; on the other hand, I will pad the array with default value, if the sentence length is shorter. So if it is vector (instead of list), do you have better suggestion for the data preprocessing ?

Comment: Don't pad - your data will be completely. mixed up. Use `CountVectorizer` or `HashingTF` and transform output (`SparseVector`) to something that your code can consume :)